# Cloudfront prohibit a user from using a read-presigned url to make an upload

Tags: api, asp.net-core, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Using the cloudfront to read and write in the same S3 bucket, how can I prohibit a user from using a read-presigned url to make an injection (upluad)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Deny access to PUT for cloudfront and it won't be able to put data into s3. In s3 permissions you can allow read only calls from cloudfront only. Turn off public access on s3, to make sure it will allow gets only from cloudfront. On CloudFront use this to update s3 bucket access, before this disable any public access on s3. CF will update S3's policy & create CF origin access identity:

[image]

To put data into S3, use presigned URL and it all goes down to the place where you create the presigned URL for upload. You may have api gateway RESTfull tiny api which would authenticate user to get the upload url and would return the upload url, which would be used by user to upload data to S3.

Comment: thank you Lukas for your detailed answer !